# How to see a list of proprietary software installed in Ubuntu? Including ALL

Tags: 20.04, privacy, gnu

Is there any command to list only proprietary software installed or have been ever since Ubuntu was newly installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [virtual Richard M. Stallman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vrms) and he will tell you if you've installed any proprietary software or not.

```
sudo apt install vrms
```

And then run `vrms` in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you. I've found 79 non free packages , mostly nvidia and found one that provided by ubuntu `fonts-ubuntu` , i am trying to uninstall it.

Comment: @edward Yes, unfortunately, non-free hardware is all that stands against us using 100% Free Software.

Comment: I am sure in future, one buddha would born to make this happen, make all free ,saves our privacy.

Comment: Probably nothing will list software that has been installed completely outside of the package management system, using software's own installers - and that's quite often the case with proprietary software

Comment: @raj , yes, i had unfortunately installed msteam , but it is not showing here anyway. 
Also @SMMousaviSP, how can i remove `fonts-ubuntu` from ubuntu. Help

Comment: @SMMousaviSP : I have tried this but I know I have software like MS Teams installed as well as Matlab (definitely not free!) that are not picked up by `vrms`.

Comment: I am trying a solution using `dpkg-query` and a clever set of filters using `grep` but the list is still quite long and many false positives.